# Mesh Analysis Question

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

When using the mesh method to solve a circuit, we will form a closed loop in the circuit and the sum of the voltages in the loop is zero. We're supposed to treat each loop independent of one another.

For loop blue, why do we have to take account for the current of the green loop? example $-Vs + R_1I_1 + R_2(I_1 + I_2) = 0$. Can we treat the blue loop as an independent loop and pretend that it is the only loop in the circuit?

Note: Please I understand that this will be easier to solve with nodal analysis with higher potential and lower potential between nodes (which I finally understand thanks to this site) or source transformation. I'm looking to understand the mesh method only.

[image]

Comment: Also see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction . I think it is actually this law applied to each closed circuit (assuming that $\partial_t B=0$ and using equations like Ohm's law etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing really "new" about solving a circuit using the mesh method, compared with nodal analysis. You just set up the equations using KCL and KVL, and solve them.

The clever part is that because you choose the current in each loop to represent the all in the circuit currents, *all of the KCL equations at the nodes are automatically satisfied*.

In your example, at the node between $R_1$ and $R_2$, the currents flowing into the node are $I_1$ through $R_1$, $I_2$ through the wire in loop b, and $-I_1-I_2$ through $R_2$. So the KCL equation is $I_1 + I_2 - I_1 - I_2 = 0$ which is true just $0 = 0$, and it is true for *any* possible values of $I_1$ and $I_2$.

If you choose the loops so that they are "independent", this happens for the KCL equation at *every* node in the circuit, so you only have to set up and solve the KVL equations for each loop.

If you write the KVL equations for the same loops that you used to define the currents, then (obviously) you get the correct number of equations to solve - one equation for each unknown current. You *could* choose a different set of loops and write the KVL equations for those, but there is no point in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply applying KVL to the blue loop. Note that the current passing through $R_2$ is $I_1+I_2$ and that should be used to calculate $R_2$'s voltage drop.

Because current is additive, mesh analysis makes use of superposition to work. You aren't treating the loops as "independent" but you are treating them as "stackable".

Answer (score 0):

> For loop blue, why do we have to take account for the current of the
>   green loop?

It really is just this simple:  since R2 is on the boundary of mesh 1 and mesh 2, *both* mesh currents are through R2.

Just apply KCL (sum of currents into the node equals the sum of currents out of the node) at the 'top' of R2:

$$I_1 + I_2 = I_{R2}$$

Maybe I'm missing something but it seems to me that this is all there is to it.

$$ $$